Android new app is not getting reviewed in Play Console
I have setup a Organizational account in Google play console and account is in already verified status. And I'm trying to publish a new app since 30th March and still Its showing under review.
I had make sure no meta data update since the last submission on 30th March. Also I contacted google team and they responded with a case no saying its still under review (around 1 week after the submission). However its been 15 days now and google is not responding to my support case though multiple followups.
Attached the screenshot and internal status track showing draft and app status is under review.
Is 15 days review time is normal or I'm missing something here?




No, waiting longer than 5-10 days is not normal. I publish lots of apps for clients and have recently experienced the same with 2 apps. Uploading a new build and submitting that for review didn't help either in my case. I think your (and my) best bet is to contact Google about it: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/contact/general_contact
